# How can i update a locally updated value inside a function and set the answer to a global variable outside the function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I Want to Add Points when those buttons are clicked and the total should be send back to points1 . and points1 should be updated each time so that if another button is clicked the update points1 value should be called in the button instead of zero.

'

```
 var points1 = 0
var pointsGiven = 25
var pointsGivenL = 35
var pointsGivenp = 15


@IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    logout()
}

@IBAction func kcalButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var points2 = self.points1
    points2 = points1 + pointsGiven
    points1 = points2
    print(points1)
           self.beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
}

@IBAction func luluButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var points2 = self.points1
    points2 = points1 + pointsGivenL
    points1 = points2
    print(points1)
      self.beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region1)
}


@IBAction func pizzahutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var points2 = self.points1

    points2 = points1 + pointsGivenp

   points1 = points2
    self.beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region2)
     print(points1)
}
```

Comment: What's problem are you having, exactly? What results are you seeing? What do you expect to see?

Comment: When i click on the button i get an increment of points1 but the problem is it does not get applied to the global variable issued outside the function , meaning if the func pizzahutbutton is clicked and a value of 25 is made points1 does not change from 0  to  25 globally . i want points1 to change to 25 globally once the button is clicked , so that if i click another button that 25 is the initial value

Comment: This code works fine, assuming all this code is inside your view controller. `points1` is an instance variable and will be updated when you set `points1 = points2` Is there another declaration of `points1` elsewhere? You refer to `self.points1` in some places and just `points1` in others

Comment: sorry about that :c . ive fixed the code . but even then the increment only seems to be happening inside the function and the final value of points1 which is being updated inside the function does not seem to make an effect on the points1 variable declared outside the function

Comment: try using `self.points1` inside your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, your code works fine - I tested it out as you posted it in your question, and `points1` is being updated as expected.

Possible issues…

- If there's another declaration of a `var points1` elsewhere this could be causing your problem.
- For some reason you're creating a new instance of the containing class, and checking *its* `points1` value , rather than the one you're updating.

So you can see what's happening to `points1` add the following to it's declaration…

```
var points1 = 0 {
    didSet {
        print("New points1 value = \(points1)")
    }
}
```